# TypeORM: many to many: Get all teams from userID

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have two table: User and Team.

They are in a many-to-many relation.

I would like to get all teams of a specific user.

Seams really simple but I can't find the answer anywhere..

Do you know how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

On the many-to-many relation must be 3rd table. This table contained user_id and team_id connections.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    first_name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(200) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE team (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    team_name varchar NOT NULL,
    team_about text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT team_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_team (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    user_id int4 NOT NULL,
    team_id int4 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_team_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- filter and select team by user_id 
select t.* from examples.team t
inner join examples.user_team usrt on usrt.team_id = t.id 
where usrt.user_id = 2;
```